# Bootstrap responsive fullwidth and mobile nav

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I expand my backgrounds fullwidth when resizing the browser. I get 10px whitespace on each side.

You can test it [here](http://www.posterlikes.com/page/)

Also the mobile navigation is not looking great. Why is it messed up ?

It is not centered, and is on top of the toggle button.

Comment: did you find some errors about offset is there in console..

Comment: How do i check that ?

Comment: If you're using Firefox, you can install Firebug, if you're using Chrome, the console/dev tools are built in to help you find exactly what you're looking for -  in this case, identifying where the CSS is applying 10px and change it.

Comment: okay, I have firebug. But cant find out where the problem is.

Comment: I think this is how bootstrap is..So it is not a problem. I just want to add 10px on each side how can i do that ?